# Hiding a portlet based on a property (not Roles) liferay

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I have a scenario where a specific portlet should not be visible when a particular property is set. 
eg:: hide.webPortlet=true

When the above property is set to true in the properties I have to hide the webPortlet portlet . So that it is no longer visible even if user have a appropriate role.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to not load the portlet or just to not load its content?

In the first case I think you have to modify Liferay core behaviour.

In the latter case there are different solution you can follow... Just to provide an example, your portlet main controller (if once, otherwhise your portlet controllers) should perform a check to your property and, if true, to redirect output to an empty JSP file. In this case, configuring your portlet without any border, your portlet will result like absent/hidden.

Comment: Can you please   redirect me to an example on how it is done. So that I can try redirecting to empty jsp.

Comment: What's the controller you are using? The example depends by it. Meanwhile you can start reading this very useful post (I'm sure it contain a solution to your problem): https://www.liferay.com/it/web/meera.success/blog/-/blogs/liferay-mvc-portlet-development-introduction